# On the fly route generation with Mojolicious::Lite

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

    get '/test' => sub {
        
        my $host = 'test';
        my ( $c ) = @_;
        
        
    my $ua  = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    
    
    my $tx = $ua->get($host => {accept => 'application/json'});
    
        
        return $c->render(
            json => $tx->res->json
        );
    };
    app->start;
```

when run this with Perl myscript.pl daemon and connect let's say https://127.0.0.1:3000/test it will run the code against test

My question how can I make the route dynamic like if i am connecting to https://127.0.0.1:3000/test2 it will run the code against test2 and not test , any idea how to achieve something like this with Mojolicious::Lite.

Comment: What do you mean by _run the code against test2_ ? Dispatch to a sub `test2` ?  Send your get req to another host "test2"? Or are you askimg about params or placeholders?

Comment: It looks like you've made an infinite loop. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear , i want to change the placeholder that every time generate different response based on the provided host instead of 'test' placeholder

Comment: Read about placeholders here: https://metacpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/view/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing.pod#Routes

Comment: Or use [param](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Message/Request#param) to access GET or POST parameters.